# Correct syntax in php

Tags: php, html

I'am tryig to print an id this way

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php isset($_REQUEST['code'])?echo'id="csv-form"':echo 'id="edit-form"'; ?> >
```

But I get this error `syntax error, unexpected 'echo'`

How is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : 
echo should be before the condition

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php echo isset($_REQUEST['code'])? 'id="csv-form"':'id="edit-form"'; ?> >
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is incorrect structure.
You should code like that:

```
echo isset($_REQUEST['code']) ?  'id="csv-form"' : 'id="edit-form"';
```

Answer (score 0):

echo is a statement, not a function and hence can not be used in ternary operators, while using ternaries, please use echo outside ....

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator has the form `condition ? expression : expression` while you wrote in your code `condition ? statement : statement`.

You should write it like this:

```
echo isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? 'id="csv-form"' : 'id="edit-form"'
```